# Displaying varying Wordpress content using get_template_part

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working on a Wordpress landing page template and the way I want it to work is that each content-xxxxxx contains a different block of text/images etc. Then on the Front Page I can call them like;

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div class="container">

    <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'featuredcontent'); ?>
    <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'textblock'); ?>

</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Which is great and works fine, but I want to be able to choose the order of the blocks from within WordPress without having to edit the front-page.php file, does anyone have any idea or code that can help with this?

Thanks

Comment: There are a few things you'll need to do. You'll need to create your own Theme Options page, or use [Option Tree](http://wordpress.org/plugins/option-tree/) to define the order in which you would like your template parts to appear. Once that's done, you can either iterate through the relevant option values and output the template parts on the front page itself, or wrap it all up in a single function call and replace the calls to get_template_part with your single function call.

Comment: another option, you can create metabox which held the dropdown list for each number of your get_template_part. in this way you can prioritize your files from back-end.

Comment: An excellent point, @KrunalShah. If the template part order is to be handled on a case-by-case basis, then a Metabox within the Post/Page Editor would make the most sense.